# Django ORM join a Raw Query

Tags: django, django-orm

I want to join a fairly complex subquery to a Django ORM queryset:

The resulting query should be like:

```
select id from webshop_product
left outer join (
    select product_id, count(extra_col) as quantity from (
        select product_id, col1 as extra_col from xyz where x = 123 and y = 456
        union
        select product_id, col2 as extra_col from abc where a = 234 and y = 534
     ) as t1
) as t2 on t2.product_id = webshop_product.id
```

The joined subquery in the left outer join clause is quite complex, it involves aggregating from a union from different tables, and I can not write it in the ORM. I tried writing it in the ORM, but I could not achieve the UNION on different tables.... so I want to join it as raw subquery, and annotate the quantity column.

Something like:

```
Product.objects.all().join("my complex raw subquery")
```

Is this possible in the Django ORM?

Comment: - If you could share your database schema it will be helpful to give more solid answers
- can't you use [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)
-  You could go with a full  [RawQuery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/sql/) **watch out for sql injection**
- Regarding UNION django has support for [UNION](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#union)

Comment: @AmirHeshmati, subqueries written as columns, are way slower than joining the subquery. RawQuery will not allow you to further filter the resulting queryset, which is convinient (for example, in this particular case I want to enclose this in the ModelManager).

In this case I treid with the Union, but I ran into problems because it was on a different model. In any case the main that I am trying to do is the ability to annotate a column from a joined raw query.

Comment: No, an explicit this freely shaped join is not possible with django ORM, as far as I am aware. A quick workaround would be to misuse the __in operator (slightly worse runtime) - `Webshop.objects.filter(product__in=<raw query goes here>)`. For that to work properly, the raw query must already contain/reduce to the product pk values in question.

Comment: Another _hacky_ way i think you can achieve this is to introduce a `managed = False` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#managed)) model to your django models and setting it up on a [Database View](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-createview.html) so you could use the ORM normally. You also might be able to do all you need with ORM then get the sql representation from it (`queryset.query` will generate the sql) and then manipulate the sql then use a `Managet.raw()`. I don't know if django purely supports this temp named table join you are trying to achieve.